# How do I stop svg GaussianBlur from being clipped?

Tags: svg

The top and bottom of my blurred circles get clipped somehow, even though the SVG element itself has plenty of extra room.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

```css
svg { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<!doctype html><html><head></head><body>
<p>Hmm</p></head></html>
<p><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="300">
  <filter id="blur"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" /></filter>
  <defs><g id="circ"><circle cx="0" cy="0" r="100" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="20px"/></g></defs>
  <g filter="url(#blur)">
  <use href="#circ" x="130" y="140" />
  <use href="#circ" x="430" y="140" />
  </g>
</svg></p>
</body></html>
```

[image]

Comment: increase the height and width of the filter and decrease the x and y. Defaults are 120% for height/width and -10% for x and y.

Comment: thanks -- `<filter id="blur" height="130%" y="-15%">` fixes it